# Multiple images/objects recognition in a single image

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I am looking for a best approach for the following problem:

I have 10.000 images, pictures (art or cliparts) to be more precise. I am looking for a method to search for those images appearing in the evaluation image ( the evaluation image may contain any number of 10.000 images, but in most cases will be none to 4 ).

Here is an example:
10.000 images are pictures published in newspaper in a last year. The evaluation image is the newspaper scan. I want to find which picture ( of 10.000 ) appears on the scan.
It's important to know **which** image appears and not just "one of training set" appears.

Ideas?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I looked into opencv and scikit, but i didn't find the case. It's looks possible to search images one-by-one, which is extremely slow. I didn't find anything else yet...

Comment: (opencv i checked the Features2D + Homography)